# Playing youtube video in vaadin MediaComponent(Mediaelementjs Player add on)

Tags: video, youtube, vaadin, mediaelement.js

I am trying to play youtube video in vaadin MediaComponent. What I did

```
ExternalResource externalResource = new ExternalResource(formatUrl(url));
externalResource.setMIMEType(MediaComponent.Type.VIDEO.name().toLowerCase());
    MediaComponent videoPlayer = new MediaComponent(MediaComponent.Type.VIDEO);
    videoPlayer.setWidth(665.0f, Unit.PIXELS);
    videoPlayer.setHeight(465.0f, Unit.PIXELS);
    videoPlayer.setSource(externalResource);
    videoPlayer.play();
    cssLayout.addComponent(videoPlayer);
```

If I define any other URL, i.e. new ExternalResource("pathToMp4.mp4") it works perfectly. So, what is so "special" about youtube videos? Any suggestion what am I doing wrong?

Cheers, Simon

Answer (score 0):

MP4 file you provided is an actual video which can be converted to a stream played by vaadin media player. If you tried an URL of youtube video, you probably used an url of a youtube page where is that video embedded, which is not the vide itself and cannot be converted to a stream to be used with vaadin media player.

You can either embedd the actual youtube video on your web page or use vaadin add-on specifically designed to play youtube video:

```
https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/youtubeplayer:vaadin
```

> YouTubePlayer component seamlessly integrates YouTube video player
>   into a Vaadin application.
>
> The server-side API features all standard playback controls: cue,
>   play, pause, stop, seek, volume, mute and quality as well as state,
>   quality, error callbacks. Supports both "chromeless" and "embedded"
>   modes.
>
> Use this YouTube player when you need better programmatic playback
>   controls than with the default embedded YouTube player. See also see
>   the interactive demo application.

Comment: I can not use vaadin youtubeplayer add-on as I use Vaadin 7.3.8.

My youtube URL link is "http://www.youtube.com/v/9dfWzp7rYR4&autoplay=1".

I tried to embedd youtube video, set full size to layout and full size to video, but have a problem, i.e. on iPad the video doesn't get full size (works fine on PC browsers).

`code`
cssLayout.setSizeFull();
  
Embedded eYoutube = new Embedded(null, new ExternalResource(formatUrl(url)));
eYoutube.setMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
eYoutube.setSizeFull();
cssLayout.addComponent(eYoutube);
`code`